# How to set elements of a list who' valus are returning from two different lists?

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

I have a list List accountInfo and AccountInfo object has multiple values who's some of the values should be set by values returning from one list say ListotherList1 and some other values of AccountInfo should be set by values returning from othe list say ListbotherList2.

How to accomplish this task. Can anyone suggest ?

Comment: Give some example. The text description is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The text description is really not very clear, but I'll offer you some code that might help:

```
package com.so.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    private class AccountInfo
    {
        public int value1 = 0;
        public int value2 = 0;
        public int value3 = 0;
        public int value4 = 0;
        public AccountInfo(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
        {
            value1 = v1;
            value2 = v2;
            value3 = v3;
            value4 = v4;
        }
    };
    void fillMainListWithSomeValuesFromAandSomeFromb(
            final List<AccountInfo> accountInfo,
            final List<AccountInfo> otherLista,
            final List<AccountInfo> otherListb)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<10;++i) {
            final AccountInfo objectInOtherLista = otherLista.get(i);
            final AccountInfo objectInOtherListb = otherListb.get(i);
            // For each value decide whether it comes from a or b
            int v1 = objectInOtherLista.value1; // use otherLista
            int v2 = objectInOtherListb.value2; // use otherListb
            int v3 = objectInOtherListb.value3;
            int v4 = objectInOtherLista.value4;
            // Create the combined AccountInfo
            final AccountInfo someData = new AccountInfo(v1,v2,v3,v4);
            // and add it to the accountInfo list
            accountInfo.add(someData);
        }
    }
    void demo()
    {
        final List<AccountInfo> accountInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<AccountInfo> otherLista = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<AccountInfo> otherListb = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;++i) {
            final AccountInfo someDataa = new AccountInfo(i,i*i,i+3,2*i);
            final AccountInfo someDatab = new AccountInfo(i+7,3*i,5*i,3*i);
            otherLista.add(someDataa);
            otherListb.add(someDatab);
        }
        // Prepared some test data; now merge the lists
        fillMainListWithSomeValuesFromAandSomeFromb(
            accountInfo,
            otherLista,
            otherListb);        
    }
}
```